# IndexError: list index out of range google-api linkedin

Tags: python, api, indexoutofrangeexception, index-error

*Hello guys,
The code can be seen below(doesn't belong to me) and I'm trying to run it without the environment path which is ok because I used to just run it with python.exe (open with). The code is used for creating an excel file with contact details and some other information with the data.

But now when I try to run the command, I get the following error for some reason. Any help would be appreciated since I'm new to API.
Thank you.*

**The code I run on cmd which contains the two inputs**

after opening the file location (cd)

```
lee.py "<job_role + 'email me at' + company>" 10
```

**The Error:**

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
File "C:\Users\z003wdaf\Desktop\linkedin\lee.py", line 15, in <module>
search_term = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**The code:**

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build                     
import datetime as dt                                           
import sys                                                      
from xlwt import Workbook                                       
import re                                                      

if __name__ == '__main__':
now_sfx = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
output_dir = './output/'
output_fname = output_dir + 'srch_res_' + now_sfx + '.xls'

search_term = sys.argv[1]
num_requests = int(sys.argv[2])

my_api_key = "My API Key"                 
my_cse_id = "011658049436509675749:gkuaxghjf5u"        

service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=my_api_key)

wb=Workbook()
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet(search_term[0:15])
wb.save(output_fname)
sheet1.write(0,0,'Name')
sheet1.write(0,1,'Profile Link')
sheet1.write(0,2,'Snippet')
sheet1.write(0,3,'Present Organisation')
sheet1.write(0,4,'Location')
sheet1.write(0,5,'Role')
sheet1.write(0,6,'Email')
sheet1.col(0).width = 256 * 20
sheet1.col(1).width = 256 * 50
sheet1.col(2).width = 256 * 100
sheet1.col(3).width = 256 * 20
sheet1.col(4).width = 256 * 20
sheet1.col(5).width = 256 * 50
sheet1.col(6).width = 256 * 50
wb.save(output_fname)

row = 1 


def google_search(search_term, cse_id, start_val, **kwargs):
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, start=start_val, **kwargs).execute()
    return res

for i in range(0, num_requests):

    start_val = 1 + (i * 10)

    results = google_search(search_term,
        my_cse_id,
        start_val,
        num=10 
    )
    for profile in range (0, 10):
        snippet = results['items'][profile]['snippet']
        myList = [item for item in snippet.split('\n')]
        newSnippet = ' '.join(myList)
        contain = re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', newSnippet)
        if contain is not None:
            title = results['items'][profile]['title']
            link = results['items'][profile]['link']
            org = "-NA-"
            location = "-NA-"
            role = "-NA-"
            if 'person' in results['items'][profile]['pagemap']:
                if 'org' in results['items'][profile]['pagemap']['person'][0]:
                    org = results['items'][profile]['pagemap']['person'][0]['org']
                if 'location' in results['items'][profile]['pagemap']['person'][0]:
                    location = results['items'][profile]['pagemap']['person'][0]['location']
                if 'role' in results['items'][profile]['pagemap']['person'][0]:
                    role = results['items'][profile]['pagemap']['person'][0]['role']
            print(title[:-23])
            sheet1.write(row,0,title[:-23])
            sheet1.write(row,1,link)
            sheet1.write(row,2,newSnippet)
            sheet1.write(row,3,org)
            sheet1.write(row,4,location)
            sheet1.write(row,5,role)
            sheet1.write(row,6,contain[0])
            print('Wrote {} search result(s)...'.format(row))
            wb.save(output_fname)
            row = row + 1

print('Output file "{}" written.'.format(output_fname))
```

Comment: Any chance that's not exactly your input and you have unprotected `<` and/or `>` on the command line that are interpreted by `cmd` as redirecting, so something like `foo <bar> 32` actually becomes a call of `foo` with _zero_ arguments and an input redirected from file `bar` and an output redirected to file `32`‽

Comment: What would be the correct format for entering the 2 inputs("<job_role + 'email me at' + company>" 10) on cmd then? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is expecting two inputs in the command line when you run the file - the first input will be your search term and the second will be the amount of requests.

Instead of running just `python.exe C:\Users\z003wdaf\Desktop\linkedin\lee.py` in your terminal add some extra arguments:

```
python.exe C:\Users\z003wdaf\Desktop\linkedin\lee.py random_thing 5
```

Where you replace `random_thing` and `5` with whatever you want.

Comment: I have edited and added the command I run which contains the 2 inputs.
I have tried it in the format that you recommended too but I got the same error message.